# XML quoting in Python

Tags: python, xml, quoting

How to quote XML to get the string with quoted control characters in python?

Source string:

```
<root namespace="value" id="guid">
    <child name="child1">Content</child>
</root>
```

Result string:

```
<root namespace=\"value\" id=\"guid\">\n    <child name=\"child1\">Content<\/child><\/root>
```

Comment: I beg you surely, what you do and what is you purpose here? Supply more information of your problem.

Comment: Are you asking about the `repr()` function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find information about how to escape/unscape xml entities in the `python.org` [wiki](http://wiki.python.org/moin/EscapingXml). In particular, there's a section about quoting attributes with `xml.sax.saxutils.quoteattr` which seems to be what you're looking for.